# List three different sound (ogg) files with ability to play on click?

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool, ogg

I have three sound files: sound1.ogg, sound2.ogg and sound3.ogg. Each are a couple seconds in length and are stored in the `/res/raw` folder in my project.

I would like them in a `ListView` on my main_activity with the ability to play the clip when the user touches the corresponding clip name.

Could someone post me an example of how this would be done? I've spent 3 days so far looking at soundpool and I'm still scratching my head.

I'm not very good with java

Comment: Have you looked at [a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/#tutorial_soundpool) and tried to follow it?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will play a sound based on the position of the item clicked. All that is in the main xml file here is a ListView with the ID listview1.
You should be able to change the r.raw references and the id of your list view and this code will work.

There are loads of tutorials out there and you will  learn much better if you attempt things like this yourself instead of asking for the answers.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SoundPool sp;
String sounds[] = {"sound1","sound2","sound3"};
private ListView lv;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sound1 = sp.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
    sound2 = sp.load(this, R.raw.sound2,1);
    sound3 = sp.load(this, R.raw.sound3,1);


    lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sounds));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(position == 0){
                sp.play(sound1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            }else if (position == 1){
                    sp.play(sound2,1,1,0,0,1);

                }else if (position == 2){
                    sp.play(sound3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                }


    }
    });



}      
}
```